# How to only get last 30 days of contntent in strapi

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, request, strapi

hope you are all having a good week so far.

I'm trying to only fetch the last 30 days of posts on my strapi back end but can't seem to figure it out...

this is what I have so far:

```
`/api/updates?created_at_gte=2022-04-03&created_at_lte=2022-05-03`
```

but for some reason it's still fetching all posts ...

Actually  I would like it to be by the published date though is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your query parameters are wrong.

```
const qs = require('qs');
const query = qs.stringify({
  filters: {
    username: {
      $eq: 'John',
    },
  },
}, {
  encodeValuesOnly: true,
});

await request(`/api/users?${query}`);
// GET /api/users?filters[username][$eq]=John
```

There are more examples here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#filtering

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to reprogram Strapi or filter the timestamp like an Int:

`{{host}}/api/events?filters[startTimestamp][$gte]=2023-03-26T00:00&filters[startTimestamp][$lte]=2023-02-26T23:59`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).